# Objects coordinates don't seem to make sense

Tags: modeling

As you can see in the image below, the main wall is located at -30, 40, 0.

[image]

The bar (that should become an arc) is parented to the wall, and is located at the same coordinates: -30, 40, 0.
But as you can see the origin is not the same as the parent object.
It is completely off on Z, Y and even X.

[image]

The line I would use to bend the beam, also parented to the wall, is again located at -30, 40, 0 and the position is correct.

[image]

The beam has no modifiers applied to it, except for the curve modifier, which I tried to deactivate and also remove, with no effect, and anyway the problem lies in the origin, not in the mesh. It's not a problem of mesh dislocated, but of wrong coordinates reported.

Comment: In the first and the second image you have both times the main wall selected. So of course it shows the exact same data and it does not really make sense why you posted the image twice...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-parent the object to the wall, without even de-parenting first, and this time the beam moved to the right position.
So problem solved.

But I'm still wondering what the hell happened here.

Comment: As I commented under the question, your images only show the position of the main wall. There is nothing that shows the arc at (-30, 40, 0).

Comment: But it was trust me!
Damn I went to far with working and can't recover that history state but trust me: it was off!

Comment: Well, visually it is definitely off, but seeing the screenshots I would simply guess if you would select the correct object it would also show the off values, so it was very unlikely someone could have helped with that question... glad you found a solution yourself.

Comment: Visually the mesh is off, as well as the origin was off. The origin was at the center of the mesh, so it was placed correctly in regard to the mesh. But the position coordinates simply didn't add up. The proof that something was off is that I just re-parented the object to the same parent and everything got fixed.  I'm so sorry the state is gone and I can't reproduce but that was the condition without any doubt, I checked, double checked and triple checked and tried many things before opening this post. I will add to the post if I encounter the same problem again.

Comment: The fact it changed position is not necessarily proof for anything working incorrectly before, just an indicator for probably using different parenting. Although sometimes the result of the multiple options can seem like they are all the same and it does not matter which one you choose, in fact they work quite differently. I wrote an answer with an overview, maybe this helps others as well because the mode of operation is not always clear to everybody.

Comment: It was parented correctly. I re-parented to the same object and it corrected the values.

Answer (score 0):

Parenting one object to another does not necessarily change the location, rotation or scale of an object, it depends on the parenting method you are choosing (this is just about object parenting, not vertex or armature etc.):

- *Object*: just parents one object to another without moving anything or changing any relations.

  [image: parenting: object]
- *Object (Keep Transform)*: is only relevant if the child is currently parented to a different object and should keep inherited transforms after switching parents, without previous parenting it is just like the first option *Object*
- *Object (Without Inverse)*: now this is tricky, this option takes all transforms of the child object, resets it to the parent object and applies the previous transforms additionally and the transformation values shown are relative to the parent.

  This is a little hard to comprehend. In the example it works as follows, no matter where the child's origin is, this is its base position. This will be reset to the parent object, i.e. the child moves so that its origin is at the parent's origin.

  The child's rotation of 45° will be added to the parent's base rotation of 30°. The child will still show a value of 45°, but globally on the world's axis it is rotated 45° + 30° = 75°.

  The scale seems even weirder. Before and after parenting the child shows a scale of 1.5, but the cube is smaller than before. This is because the mesh of the cube gets multiplied by the parent's scale to reset the geometry to the parent. Which means the child keeps the scale of 1.5, but the mesh had a dimension of 3m per edge before parenting, and now it is 3m × 0.5 = 1.5m.

  [image: parenting: without inverse]
- *Object (Keep Transform Without Inverse)*: visually it is like the first and second option, the child stays exactly as it is and keeps all its transforms as they are. The difference is, that these transform values are shown relative to the parent's (local) properties. Which means, the 45° angle of the child is now 15° from the the parent's 30°, the scale stays the same, and the location is (1, -2.9641, 2.86603). Okay, these decimal numbers look weird, but they are not simply the subtraction of the two origins in global coordinates, but based on the rotation of the parent object.

  [image: parenting: keep transform without inverse]

Comment: Thank you, I'll give a try to the other methods (I always use the main simple one) and see if I can reproduce the error.